# Kerning in \Cref of cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, kerning

When I use the `\Cref` command of `cleveref` package, it doesn't apply the corresponding kerning:

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}\label{thm}
    Teorema
\end{thm}
Te \\
\Cref{thm}
\end{document}
```

There is no kerning between the `T` and the `e` of `Teorema`.

### How can I solve this? Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not to be considered a bug. The capitalization is obtained by applying `\MakeUppercase`, so detaching the first letter. Just teach `cleveref` what's your preferred capitalised form:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\Crefname{thm}{Teorema}{Teoremi}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}\label{thm}
    Teorema
\end{thm}
Te \\
\Cref{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the `thref` option to `ntheorem`, as `cleveref` overrides it (and issues a warning about it).